# How to provide elasticseach index mappings to Fluentd elasticsearch ouput plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

In our fluentd kubernetes deamonset we wanted to store pod name in a separate field named as application_id. But type of this field must be keyword. For that we need to provide index mapping to elasticsearch output plugin to create index as per our need. But we did not found any key in elasticsearch output plugin to provide index mapping. Can anyone help us to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide index template in elasticsearch output plugin using `template_name` , `template_file` options:

```
<match my.logs>
  @type         elasticsearch
  host          localhost
  port          9200
  index_name    fluentd
  type_name     fluentd
  template_name template_1
  template_file /fluentd/etc/template.json
</match>
```

Please check [this issue](https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch/issues/33).

Please check this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) as well to learn about index templates.